# BorderLayout orientation

Tags: java, swing, layout, orientation, border-layout

I'm trying to create the top buttons of a window. I have a JFrame and a JPanel with the differents buttons when I try to add the panel with the buttons to a JPanel on the frame, it doesn't show... digging and trying to find the solution, I realize that the issue is when I set the orientation to the panel with the buttons on the BorderLayout panel. I think that it might be something dumb that I haven't realize but I haven't found any issue like this.

The issue is here when I set the orientation:

```
contentPanel.add(buttons,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

if I remove the:

```
BorderLayout.PAGE_START
```

it works

This is my Frame:

```
package view;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
 private JPanel contentPanel, layOutPanel;
 private CardLayout mainCardLayout;
 private BorderLayout borderLayout;
 private static MainFrame instance = null;
 private FrameButtonsPanel buttons;

private MainFrame(){
 setSize(1000,700);
 //setUndecorated(true);
 setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


 contentPanel = new JPanel();
 borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
 contentPanel.setLayout(borderLayout);
 add(contentPanel);

 buttons = new FrameButtonsPanel();
 buttons.setBackground(Color.red);
 contentPanel.add(buttons,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

 /*layOutPanel = new JPanel();
 mainCardLayout = new CardLayout();
 layOutPanel.setLayout(mainCardLayout);
 layOutPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
 contentPanel.add(layOutPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);*/
}

 public static MainFrame getInstance(){
  if (instance == null){
   instance = new MainFrame();
  }
  return instance;
 }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   MainFrame.getInstance().setVisible(true);
  }
 }
```

and this is my panel with the buttons:

```
package view;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.Spring;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

 public class FrameButtonsPanel extends JPanel{
 private Spring spring;
 private JButton iconify, maximize, close;

  public FrameButtonsPanel(){
   SpringLayout mySpring = new SpringLayout();
   setLayout(mySpring);

  iconify = new JButton("-");
  add(iconify);
  maximize = new JButton("O");
  add(maximize);
  close = new JButton("X");
  add(close);

  spring = Spring.constant(850,850,2000);


mySpring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,iconify,spring,SpringLayout.WEST,this);
mySpring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,maximize,3,SpringLayout.EAST,iconify);
mySpring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,close,3,SpringLayout.EAST,maximize);
mySpring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,this,3,SpringLayout.EAST,close);

iconifyWindow();
maximizeWindow();
closeWindow();
}

 private void iconifyWindow(){
  iconify.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        MainFrame.getInstance().setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
     }
   });
 }

 private void maximizeWindow(){
  maximize.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if(MainFrame.getInstance().getExtendedState() == JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH){
        MainFrame.getInstance().setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
    }else{
        MainFrame.getInstance().setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }
        }
     });
  }

private void closeWindow(){
  close.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no  idea why you are trying to use a SpringLayout to display buttons.

Just use a `JPanel` with a right aligned `FlowLayout`.

Read the `FlowLayout` API for more information on how to right align the components added to the panel.

Comment: It fixed the issue, any Idea why I can't do it with the spring-layout? I wanted to add some more components to the bar I'm creating, and I thought that spring would give me the more customization, anyway I think that I can work it out with FlowLayout

Comment: @DarkCrow10, I'm sure you can to it with a SpringLayout. But the SpringLayout is a complicated layout manager with many constraints. Your code didn't work because your constraints aren't correct. So why use it when the FlowLayout is so simple. If you want to experiment with the SpringLayout, then start with the working examples from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html).